# Node.js - listen on unix socket and transfer data to connected websocket (socket.io) clients

Tags: node.js, sockets, unix, socket.io, send

I have a small webcrawler written in C that collects some data from different websites and creates json-objects that are sent through a unix socket as a utf-8 encoded string.

Node.js is listening on that socket-file and receives all the json-strings.

Now the question is - how can I accomplish it, that this data is sent to all connected socket.io clients?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

On the server end:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
```

Then, when you have some data to send to all connected websockets:

```
io.emit('someMsg', data);
```

See the documentation [here](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server#emit).